# How to search for any UIWebView component usage inside a current project?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

when submitting my latest build, Apple has response with this warning.

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Fyi, I already migrate all UIWebView component to WKWebView component in my project based on Apple recommendation but Apple still response with the same warning.

Is there any ways to search for any UIWebView element that still attached to my project other that using Search functionality inside Xcode?

Comment: Maybe you are using some framework or third party tool that is using UIWebView in it. Try to update frameworks and tools.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hey I tried searching in Xcode.
Couple of the third party libraries used it. (FBSDK for example)
I updated those libraries but that wasn't sufficient.

On the next upload the scary email arrived again.

Then I found this article:
https://medium.com/@zivchen_42755/for-me-that-wasnt-enough-it-didn-t-found-all-of-them-thats-weird-something-to-do-with-pod-i-a068d55b7fab

and in the comments someone mentioned `grep` being the medicine.

So I tried `grep -r UIWebView /Path/To/Project/*`

And it found a couple of the binary frameworks that also use UIWebView. (GoogleSignin, Crashlytics ...) 
I updated those too.

On the next upload there was no scary email :D

Comment: i tried grep -r UIWebView .

found a couple of the binary frameworks and project.xcworkspace that also use UIWebView.

i cleared all and run again grep -r UIWebView . - now its cleared and i uploaded a version into the store.

Again I received ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage email:(

i tried ur suggestion, its works same as grep -r UIWebView .

any other suggestion/solution ? kindly reply ASAP

Comment: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/522
update onesignal

Comment: You can also grep the resultant executable if you need more clues as to how exactly UIWebView is being used in your app:

nm YourApp.app/YourApp | grep UIWebView

Answer (score 8):

You can find by using below command lines in your project.

```
$ cd yourprojectpath

$ grep -r "UIWebView" .
```

Answer (score 6):

`grep -r UIWebView` works fine for sources but partially for 3rd party binaries because from one side they can contain references, comments or string data with UIWebView without actually using the API and from the other they can use it but doesn't have any reference about.

To check binaries (app, static libs or dynamic frameworks) you should get symbols table with `nm` (llvm symbol table dumper) e.g.:

```sh
nm staticlib.a | grep UIWebView
0000000100117c38 t +[UIWebView(SCORVCE) load]
0000000100117c30 t +[UIWebView_SCORVCE_Importer import]
0000000100117ea4 t -[UIWebView(SCORVCE) vce_delegate]
0000000100117d54 t -[UIWebView(SCORVCE) vce_setDelegate:]
000000010012880c t -[VCETrack setUsingUIWebView:]
00000001001287fc t -[VCETrack usingUIWebView]
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView
0000000100640668 s _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView_SCORVCE_Importer
0000000100639f88 s _OBJC_IVAR_$_VCETrack._usingUIWebView
0000000100640640 s _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIWebView_SCORVCE_Importer
0000000100117ca0 t ___26+[UIWebView(SCORVCE) load]_block_invoke
```

For frameworks you should do the same with its binary file:

```
nm MyFramework.framework/MyFramework | grep UIWebView
```

Finally to be sure that the app doesn't use UIWebView you should make an archive then find your app file (YourApp.app) and run next script inside:

```sh
# Check the app with static libraries
echo "YourApp"
nm YourApp | grep UIWebView

# Check dynamic frameworks
for framework in Frameworks/*.framework; do
  fname=$(basename $framework .framework)
  echo $fname".framework"
  nm $framework/$fname | grep UIWebView
done
```