# How to find if a Java package is being used in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

My application is rejected from Play store and they have asked to remove Camera2 [ android.hardware.Camera2] feature from the App. I don't have that feature either in Manifest.xml as well as in Java source code files.

I have also verified it by using "Find in Path" across all files.

What I wanted is, to find whether this package ( android.hardware.camera2 ) is being used by any of the third-party libraries which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to see package usage from terminal (Mac OS)

```
$ cd yourprojectpath
$ grep -r "android.hardware.camera2" .
```

Above command, lists down package references from merged-manifest as well as from binary files.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720424/5212236

Answer (score 0):

You can find using dependency tree
To find internal dependencies and modules of library use mentioned command

For Android

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

If You have gradle wrapper then use

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```