# How to change UIWebView to WKWebview in firebase auth folder in react native app

Tags: swift, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-ios

I'm trying to update my app and I got this email from Apple.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

Ive located the UIWebviews and there are 24 instances in my pods/FirebaseAuth folder. How would i remove them in my app?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/819#issuecomment-526202980 Check this. I solved using following that steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step1: Open your projectname.xcworkspace in XCode.
Step2: Press cmd + shift + F
Step3: Now search "UIWebView"
Step4: Check which library using UIWebview and update that library
```

Comment: Would i update the UIWebview by manually deleting each UIWebview and replacing it WKWebview?

Comment: No you have to check library which is using UIWebView and check that libraries's doc

Answer (score 0):

You have to make next options to give up using old UIWebView:

**1. React Native**

RNCWebView component has started using `WKWebView` from version 7.0.1 so you need to update your package.js to use latest one e.g.:

```json
"react-native-webview": "^8.0.0",
```

**2. Native code**

If your project has native code ObjC/Swift with `UIWebView` you should replace with `WKWebView` and make appropriate code changes to use new API.

**3. Libraries/Pods/Frameworks**

Some your old third party libraries can use `UIWebView` so you should find them and update to the latest version which can use new `WKWebView`. How to check your libraries/frameworks or your entire app for `UIWebView` look at this answer - [How to search for any UIWebView component usage inside a current project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091231/how-to-search-for-any-uiwebview-component-usage-inside-a-current-project/63724703#63724703)

Comment: how do i update the libraries? do i type pod update in the terminal?

Comment: If you don't pick the version of your dependency in pod file you can just make `pod update`, if you make changes in pod file call `pod install`.