# GoogleSignInSDK usages of UIWebView

Tags: ios, google-signin

Anyones knows from which version of GoogleSignInSDK(iOS) the usages of UIWebView has been removed, does version 4.4.0 covers that?

Answer (score 5):

Since there isn't any mention, regarding this matter, in the official [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release), you can use the suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689202/6791677) answer to determine which version has removed the references to `UIWebView`.

Running `grep -r UIWebView .` command in your project directory, will have as an output the files in which the "UIWebView" string appears, **even the binary ones**.

I went ahead and installed `GoogleSignIn` in an empty project. It seams that version 4.4.0 still uses `UIWebView`. The result of `grep -r UIWebView .` in the project directory was:

> ```
> ~ grep -r UIWebView .
> ./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,
> Binary file ./Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn matches
> ```

Clearly a binary file inside `GoogleSignIn.framework` contains such a reference.

But since version 5.0.0 there are references of `UIWebView` only in `README.md` and `CHANGELOG.md` files:

> ```
> ~ grep -r UIWebView .
> ./Pods/AppAuth/README.md:for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly *not*
> ./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,
> ```

So if you want to upload an new application in the App Store you probably need to upgrade to at least version 5.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Last month I faced this problem. A lot of googling finally resolved this issue by the following way.

1. Just comment out all the pod library and try with this pod file only

   ```
   pod 'GoogleSignIn'
   ```

and then take

```
 pod install
```

2. then paste this line in the terminal

   ~ grep -r UIWebView .

Note: Notice above line has a dot(.) in the last letter and check there no 'UIWebView' found.

3. if there is no 'UIWebView' found then this pod file is okay.
4. again uncollment one pod file and repeat step 1, step 2 and step3. One by one is necessary because one pod file may depends on another pod file.

if you follow these steps carefully then I hope 'UIWebView' will remove from all pod file.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can fixed by using
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 6.0.2'

this thread is save my life.
Hope this help.

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/pull/205#issuecomment-1370534648

// can solve the google login fail on iOS

// GoogleSignInSDK don't use UIWebView anymore.

PS. I'm using Unity 2021.3.25f1 on 2023 :D